# Togglz not getting started with SpringBoot 3.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, togglz

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @3feb2e2b; javax.servlet.Filter is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @42eca56e)

SpringBoot version - 3.1.2
Togglz version - 4.0.0

tried below versions
SpringBoot version - 3.1.2
Togglz version - 4.0.0-M4

Comment: Spring Boot 3.x is for JakartaEE, the togglz version you are using is for Javaee and thus not compatible. Either wait for a compatible version of find another library that does feature toggles. Please add your dependencies as looking at the 4.0 documentation that should be compatible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.